# selecting every 3 consecutive elements starting from 1 by using nth selector

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

i want to use the nth child selector to select my elements as shown in the example image below (the blue color elements are the ones that need to be selected, i have painted them blue in order to refer to ). I tried a lot of almost similar answers available but could not get the exact one. so, if anyone can please give me a solution, I would appreciate it.[nth child selectors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z167S.png)

Comment: Please post a [mcve] showing us the HTML and CSS you've tried

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the `:not` selector combined with `:nth-child` selector.

```css
ul li:not(:nth-child(4n)) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Some text</li>
  <li>Some text</li>
  <li>Some text</li>
  <li>Some text</li>
  <li>Some text</li>
  <li>Some text</li>
  <li>Some text</li>
  <li>Some text</li>
  <li>Some text</li>
  <li>Some text</li>
  <li>Some text</li>
  <li>Some text</li>
  <li>Some text</li>
  <li>Some text</li>
  <li>Some text</li>
  <li>Some text</li>
</ul>
```